# emacsclient directly start eshell command command line

Tags: eshell, emacsclient, customize, command-line-arguments, emacs-daemon

Both of the following work to call a graphical/terminal eshell:

- `emacs -f eshell`
- `emacs -nw -f eshell`

Furthermore, this 2-step process also works:

- `emacsclient -t -a '' /some/real/file/name
- <kbd>Meta</kbd><kbd>x</kbd> `eshell`

*BUT*, this does not:

- `emacsclient -t -a '' -f eshell`

and fails with this error after lots of normal startup messages:

```
Error: server did not start correctly
Error: Could not start the Emacs daemon
```

<sub>Note: On my system, I use `alias edt="emacsclient -t -a ''` to make sure that I always end up in a daemon-backed emacs session server</sub>

How can I, in one command,

- launch `emacsclient`
- launch and display a new `eshell`
- OR display an existing `eshell` frame?

<sub>If I could also suppress the top 2 "Welcome to EShell" lines, that would also be useful</sub>

EDIT: I found this way of launching emacs with eval:

`emacsclient -t -a '' --eval '(eshell)'`

, but this *always* selects the pre-existing eshell. How would I then get a "new" one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Surprisingly (at least to me), the `-f` flag means different things to emacs and emacsclient. To emacs, it means:

> -f FUNCTION
>    --funcall=FUNCTION
>
> Call Lisp function FUNCTION.  If it is an interactive function (a
>        command), it reads the arguments interactively just as if you had
>        called the same function with a key sequence.  Otherwise, it calls
>        the function with no arguments.

Whereas for emacsclient:

> -f SERVER-FILE
>   --server-file=SERVER-FILE
>
> Specify a “server file” for connecting to an Emacs server via TCP.

So that's one problem solved. As for starting a new `eshell` session, from the help (`C-h f eshell <return>`):

> (eshell &optional ARG)
>
> Create an interactive Eshell buffer.
>   The buffer used for Eshell sessions is determined by the value of
>   `eshell-buffer-name'.  If there is already an Eshell session active in
>   that buffer, Emacs will simply switch to it.  Otherwise, a new session
>   will begin.  A numeric prefix arg (as in `C-u 42 M-x eshell RET')
>   switches to the session with that number, creating it if necessary.  **A
>   nonnumeric prefix arg means to create a new session.**  Returns the
>   buffer selected (or created).

So we can get a fresh `eshell` process in an emacsclient with:

```
emacsclient -e '(eshell t)'
```