# emacs start with eshell focused using .emacs config file

Tags: eshell

It's possible to start `emacs` with an `eshell` buffer focused using the `-f` flag as described in [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/24229/emacsclient-directly-start-eshell-command-command-line).

```
> emacs -nw -f "eshell"
```

I'm wondering if there's a way of launching `eshell` and focusing its buffer using just the `.emacs` file.

Using the following files, I've been able to *start* `eshell` automatically, but not to shift focus to its corresponding buffer, named `*eshell*` by default.

```
; .emacs.d/init.el
(eshell)
```

and

```
; .emacs.d/init.el
(eshell)
(switch-to-buffer "*eshell*)
```

Is there a way to switch focus to the `eshell` buffer from the `.emacs` file without using a command line argument?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A major obstacle is that `startup.el` is hard-coded into the Emacs executable and that file does some buffer switching that varies depending upon certain things.  People also load things like restoring the prior desktop using `desktop.el`, which uses the `after-init-hook` and does some buffer switching.  There are probably a lot of other popular startup options and libraries that do some buffer switching.  The last hook to load is the `emacs-startup-hook`, so the O.P. may wish to use something like this:

```
(add-hook 'emacs-startup-hook 'eshell)
```

Comment: I shortened the example to eliminate `switch-to-buffer` because `eshell` contains `pop-to-buffer-same-window`.

Comment: Do commands like `eshell` normally contain `pop-to-buffer-same-window` calls? It might be worth having the more verbose/explicit version as an option in case someone wants to try this with not-eshell.

Comment: The authors of the various Emacs libraries make decisions regarding how/where to display a particular buffer.  There is no rule of thumb.  The most common approach is to use the `display-buffer-alist` to control how certain buffers are displayed.  There are also libraries that assist users to control how buffers are displayed.  I personally prefer the create/locate approach and then I display buffers however/wherever I want.  Here are two examples of how I do it:  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28730/2287 and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/28924/2287 .